# @trigger_error E_USER_DEPRECATED is throwing status 500

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

In my Symfony 3.3 application I get a status 500 when I call [`$this->environment = $environment;`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Form/TwigRendererEngine.php#L37). Shouldn’t an `E_USER_DEPRECATED` error just continue?

There is no further information in the Symfony dev log or the Apache error log.

Environment: apache2, php 5.6.30-0+deb8u1

This happens while I’m working with SonataAdminBundle and want to add a second admin with `sonata_type_collection`.

When I clicked on the “New” button for a OneToMany relation, I saw this error in my network inspector.